# Is it always necessary to use a falling tone in referring expressions?

Tags: intonation

Is it always necessary to use a falling tone in referring expressions?

I know that it is sometimes used but do native speaker sometimes ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect from your question that you may be a native speaker of Mandarin or some other language in which tones are critical to meaning and are formally defined. In English there is no such definition and tones are used dependent on context and to indicate context, the most obvious example being that a rising tone at the end of a sentence usually indicates a question; although some people in all English-speaking countries, and most people in some English-speaking countries use a rising tone at the end of statements to the annoyance and amusement of the rest of us. So the answer to your question is no, there is no general rule for the use of a particular tone in referring expressions: the tone used for a referring expression is dependent on the context just like any other part of speech. For example one man may say to another "My wife has just been awarded a PhD" using a rising tone on 'wife' and applying emphasis to the same word. The second man may say "My wife has just given birth to twins" stressing 'My' and using a falling tone on 'wife' to emphasise the contrast between the two women and the significant events which have occurred to them. I'm afraid the only way to determine the correct tone for any context is to listen to a lot of English conversations, there are no universal formal rules.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please check this page and let me know your thoughts because in that page it is mentioned that referring expressions sometimes get a falling intonation. But according to you, however, it does not, so I wonder if that article might be having other information that is not true. The article: http://iteslj.org/Techniques/Celik-Intonation.html

Comment: I'm glad that you have found my answer interesting, however I think you slightly misunderstood me. I didn't mean to suggest that any intonation is never used. I meant to suggest that almost any intonation can be uesd almost anywhere depending on the context. The article is very scholarly and quite interesting but is trying to provide a set of rules for an aspect of English which, in my experience, has very little consistency in practice. The article is probably a good start but is no substitute for listening to spoken English.